# Need assist with c++ template dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a template class and it works - but for some reason there is a problem with my dynamic allocation. initial length of arrays: old 2 new 4. the first time it works(old point on new(so now his size 4) and now, new is in the size of 8) but on the next round - it blows up on the `delete [] temp;` with heap problem. any ideas? thanks

```
template <class T>
void Log<T>::Add(T item)
{
    // If array is full
    if(m_oldSize == m_oldCount)
    {
        // prepare array switch
        T* temp = m_old;

        // Point to new array
        m_old = m_new;
        m_oldSize = m_newSize;
        m_newSize *= ARRAY_MUL;
        m_newCount = DEFAULT_COUNT;

        //delete old
        delete [] temp;
        temp = NULL;

        //create new array
        m_new = new T[m_newSize];
    }

    // Add item and update new array
    m_old[m_oldCount++] = item;
    if(m_oldCount > FIRST_ROUND)
    {
        m_new[m_newCount++]= m_old[m_newCount];
        m_new[m_newCount++]= m_old[m_newCount];
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to set `m_oldCount = 0;` inside `if` condition?

Comment: No - because m_oldCount - always says how many items i have

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to reinvent std::vector.  `#include <vector>`

Comment: I'm not allowed to use <vector>

Comment: what are m_old and m_new? why are you storing 2 lots of info in the class. Surely you just need 1 set of data, and when it's full allocate a second set, copy it over and free the first one? You may find this added complexity is hiding the real problem. Also, the ++ and then using the value later on the line may not be doing what you expect...

Comment: I agree - but that is the design I was forced to implement. I've trying seperate the lines with ++ , but nothing changed

Comment: See [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). @MooingDuck is refering to the fact your class contains a pointer to dynamically allocated data, which it presumably owns.

Comment: If `m_oldSize == m_oldCount`, you delete `m_old` (via `temp` that you initialized to `m_old`), and yet still try to use `m_old` after that.  Everything about this is bad, especially if as you say this is "what you are foced to implement".

Answer (score 0):

As this is homework I have just created a non elegant solution, you should be able to find the pitfalls and extend it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct foo
{
  foo(int h) : g(h) { }
  int g;
};

template <typename T>
class bar
{
public:
  bar() : curSize(2), curNo(0)
  {
    a = new T[curSize];
  }

  void Add(T item)
  {
    if (curNo == curSize) {
      curSize = 2 * curSize;
      T *newArray = new T[2*curSize];
      for (size_t i = 0 ; i != curNo; ++i) {
        newArray[i] = a[i];
      }
      delete[] a;
      a = newArray;

    }
    a[curNo] = item;
    ++curNo;

  }

  void print()
  {
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i != curNo; ++i) {
      cout << a[i]->g << endl;
    }
  }



private:

  size_t curSize;
  size_t curNo;
  T * a;
};


int main()
{
 foo *f1 = new foo(1);
 foo *f2 = new foo(2);
 foo *f3 = new foo(3);
 foo *f4 = new foo(4);
 bar<foo*> *g = new bar<foo*>();
 g->Add(f1);
 g->Add(f2);
 g->Add(f3);
 g->Add(f4);
 g->print();
 cout << "Add more and print" << endl;

 g->Add(f1);
 g->Add(f2);
 g->Add(f3);
 g->Add(f4);
 g->Add(f3);
 g->Add(f4);

 g->print();

}
```